# loading animated images into android imagebutton is possible?

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton, android-imageview

i want to put .GIF(Animated) image into the imagebutton into android is it is possible? i am using android sdk 1.6 (can it also possible into the image view) i've tried but image just displayes but without animation.. thanks in advance Pragna

Answer (score 0):

Gif is a supported format but I don't think that the animated is.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) doesn't really say.

Comment: @Pragna ,I tried GIF animation. for me its not working in emulator but its working in  device.Try once in device, but I dont go for GIF animation